# C# program needs access to large dataset in C++ COM quickly

Tags: c#, arrays, com, marshalling

I have a C# program that wants to process some floating point data.  The data comes from native C++ code that is 64 bits (a COM EXE) while the C# program is 32 bits.  I can pass data back and forth using SAFEARRAY, but that is very slow.

I think the ideal solution would be to allocate an array of floats on the C# side.  Use   m_FastRowPinHandle = GCHandle.Alloc(myArray, GCHandleType.Pinned);
to pin the C# array, and then have the native C++ code get the pointer to that memory and copy the floats into that array.

I had a routine that took 10.5 seconds to process the data using SAFEARRAY to pass the data back and forth.  When I changed the data processing to use Parallel.For I changed the processing from 6.5 seconds to 1.5 seconds, but the total time went from 10.5 seconds to 5.5 seconds because it took 4 seconds to transfer the data from the C++ side using SAFEARRAY to the C# side.

Do I have to use SAFEARRAY when calling COM?  If not what is the correct IDL so that I can access the m_FastRowPinHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject() on the native C++ side?  Would this be faster?  It doesn't seem like it should take 4 seconds to marshal 1 GB of float data.

Thank you,
Rick Wirch

Comment: Pass data as raw bytes with shared memory, pipe, socket and etc

Comment: It is not the safe array that makes it slow, it is having to cross a process boundary.  Bigger arrays will help cut down on the overhead but you'll never get close to the speed you get when doing this in-process.

Comment: Hi Thanks Hans.  I guess this means that I am screwed and will have to rewrite a bunch of code from C# to C++.  I have already tried adjusting the size of the buffer between the 2 worlds and it made very little difference in the speed.  It was using buffers between ~600000 floats and larger.  Tried making the buffer 32MB and it only made it about ~20% faster.

Comment: I guess the answer I was looking for, but maybe doesn't matter is how to use the m_FastRowPinHandle.AddrOfPinnedObject() which is of type IntPtr in the C++ COM side.  What IDL would be needed to use that IntPtr?

The reason that I thought this might help is when I profiled, very little time was spent doing the memcpy.  Also it seems like 4 seconds is a long darn time to pass 1 GB of memory from one process to another.